# Can I add a template inside if an IF statement? XSLT

Tags: xml, if-statement, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0

Suppose I have the following xml

```
<Requirement>
   <Name code="001">Hello</Name>
   <Day>Monday</Day>
   <Status>Open</Status>
   .
   .
   .
   --- ALOT OF OTHER DATA ---
</Requirement>
```

Now, I have an xslt

```
.
.
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xml>
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Requirement/Name/text()" />
      </ID>
      <xsl:apply templates select="@*|node()" />
   </xml>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select"@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
.
.
```

I do not want to get rid of this copy template, however I do need to add something to this xslt. I need an if statement that if Name = Hello and Status is Open then Day is Friday. If Name is not Hello then no change is needed. Can I add a template inside an if statement?

```
<xsl:if test="Name='Hello'">
   <xsl:template match="Day/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="Friday" />
   <xsl:template>
</xsl:if>
```

This is failing, but can someone suggest something similar that might help?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the match pattern on your template to include the criteria for the `Name` sibling value being "Hello" and Status sibling value of "Open":

```
<xsl:template match="Requirement[Name='Hello' and Status='Open']/Day/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="'Friday'" />
<xsl:template>
```

Then it will either match and change to Friday, or not match and hit the default template that copies.

Note that I added quotes to make it a string literal, rather than an XPath looking for an element named `Friday`, or you could instead use `<xsl:text>Friday</xsl:text>`.

Comment: @Mads Hansen, thank you for your help! I have an issue with this though. If I have a blank Day - so just <Day/> in my xml, then this approach does not work. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: *** so I decided that within the template match I’d write Day[. = ‘’ or text()] and then under that I’d write <Day>Friday</Day> seems to be working